# Can't convert bytes to JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, django-rest-framework

A serializer class ensures the data written into database is in JSON format:

```py
sh_list = serializers.JSONField(binary=True)
```

Data is visible as one of entries in an output JSON:

```
...
"sh_list": "\"[{'position': 1, 'item': 'Display'},
               {'position': 3, 'item': 'Keyboard'},
               {'position': 4, 'item': 'Headphones'}]\"",
...
```

I process it in `views.py` trying to convert the data into a dictionary:

```py
sh_list = json.loads(serializer.data["sh_list"])

print('sh_list:', sh_list)
# sh_list: [{'position': 1, 'item': 'Display'}, {'position': 3, 'item': 'Keyboard'}, {'position': 4, 'item': 'Headphones'}]
print('sh_list type:', type(sh_list))
# sh_list type: <class 'str'>

print('serializer.data["sh_list"] type:', type(serializer.data["sh_list"]))
# serializer.data["sh_list"] type: <class 'bytes'>

sh_list2 = serializer.data["sh_list"].decode()
print('sh_list2:', sh_list2)
# sh_list2: "[{'position': 1, 'item': 'Display'}, {'position': 3, 'item': 'Keyboard'}, {'position': 4, 'item': 'Headphones'}]"
print('sh_list2 type:', type(sh_list2))
# sh_list2 type: <class 'str'>

sh_list3 = json.loads(sh_list2)
print('sh_list3[0]:', sh_list3[0])
# sh_list3[0]: [
print('sh_list3 type:', type(sh_list3))
# sh_list3 type: <class 'str'>
```

Desired output for me would be something like:

```py
print('sh_list3[0]:', sh_list3[0])
# sh_list3[0]: {'position': 1, 'item': 'Display'}
```

How to proceed with conversion from bytes to a dictionary?

Comment: I get a `JSONDecodeError` because of the `'` characters. However, this fixes it: `sh_list2 = sh_list2.replace("'",'"')`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sh_list = json.loads(serializer.data["sh_list"])
```

returns a dict.

with one key "sh_list" and a string as value

This string is the problem, The code that created it is probably buggy or was not intended to return data, that can be parsed as json string.

First the string

```
"\"[{'position': 1, 'item': 'Display'},
           {'position': 3, 'item': 'Keyboard'},
           {'position': 4, 'item': 'Headphones'}]\"
```

contains a leading and a trailing double quote.
But even if you strip these off, the contents contains single quotes instead of double quotes. Json requires double quotes.

So you can fix for this particular case with

```
fixed_json = sh_list[1:-1].replace("'", '"')

aslist = json.load(fixed_json)

print(repr(aslist[0])
```

But this is definetely not robust code.
If possible I suggest to fix the problem at the source and change the code that generated these 'funny' strings

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It seems the `serializers.JSONField` transforms JSONs into single-quoted form. Standard `TextField` doesn't do anything like that. I'll check encoders, maybe applying one of these helps.

Comment: it's almost as if the hierarchical serializer creates a string version (repr) of a python object adds double quotes. Really strange.